# I can't install Python libraries due to "from pip import main cannot import name main"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, odoo, ubuntu-18.04

I am not expert in Ubuntu, so i need your help that will make my day. 
I have several versions of python on my machine because i'am working with odoo several odoo framewrok versions, after installing `odoo 10` which works on `Python 2.7`. I am deleting it and i have this issue when reinstalling.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

How can i resolve that issue?

**NOTE**
When i write `type pip` in terminal i get this location `pip is /home/autoparts/.local/bin/pip`. I thougt the pip location is not as the error above.
Any help will be appricated.

Comment: What is returned when you type the command `which -a pip`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ImportError%3A+cannot+import+name+main

Answer (score 1):

Check out this topic on Github [Pip 5447](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5447)

They offered two ways as mentioned below:

> We solved this issue by clear hash in bash:
>
> $ hash -d pip
>
> Or in dash (sh):
>
> $ hash -r pip

Or

> In this case, the particular issue seems to be:
>
> 1. pip3 install --user --upgrade pip installs pip 10 in the user site, but doesn't uninstall the system site copy of pip.
> 2. User runs the system wrapper from /usr/bin/pip3 which is from the OS-supplied pip 8. This wrapper expects to see pip 8, but it doesn't because user site takes priority over system site.
>
> The solution is to use the pip wrapper installed when you installed pip 10 in --user. That will mean changing your PATH to put that first, or using an explicit path when you invoke pip.